# Subset relation in a sequence of sets (Proof by induction)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, relations

I am trying to prove this claim:

Let $G$ be a set of ordered pairs (it is supposed to denote the graph of a relation on a set). Consider the following sequence of sets: $G_1= G$ and $G_{n+1}=G_n\cup G_nG_n$. For each $i, j\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, if $i\le j$, then $G_i\subseteq G_j$.

I know that the proof is supposed to be done by induction but I am having a hard time with what I'm supposed to carry out induction on. Should I assume that $G_i ⊆ G_j$ as my induction hypothesis to show that $G_{i+1} ⊆ G_{j+1}$ (I'm not even sure if that's valid for induction)? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $G_nG_n$? Is $G$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ or something? If so, tell us what. If not, what do you mean?

However, it doesn't actually matter what $G_nG_n$ is for the question: you could replace it with any old set that you like, and the result would still hold:  note that, by definition of $G_{i+1}$, $G_i \subseteq G_{i+1}$. A simple induction argument will then show you that $G_i \subseteq G_j$ for all $j \geq i$ (via the transitivity of $\subseteq$: if $G_i \subseteq G_j$ for some $j \geq i$, then $G_i \subseteq G_j \subseteq G_{j+1}$, so $G_i \subseteq G_{j+1}$.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but thank you for your help. G is the graph of a binary relation on a set. For example, suppose the relation R = < $D , G$ > (where the domain and codomain of the relation are both the set *D*, then G is a subset of $D^2$. By $G_nG_n$, I simply mean the composition of the graph with itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base case(s) for all $i\in\Bbb Z^+$ we clearly see $G_i\subseteq G_i$.

For the induction show for all $(i,j)\in\Bbb Z^{+2}:i\leq j$  that *if* $G_i\subseteq G_j$ *then* $G_i\subseteq G_{j+1}$

> (Ps: easily done by demonstrating for all $j\in \Bbb Z^+$ that $G_j\subseteq G_{j+1}$)

---

You are proving induction on iterations of $j$. $$\begin{split}\forall i\in\Bbb Z^+~&~P(i,i)\\ \forall i\in\Bbb Z^+~\forall j\in\Bbb Z^+~&~(P(i,j)\to P(i,j+1))\\\hline\therefore\quad \forall i\in\Bbb Z^+~\forall j\in\Bbb Z^+~&~P(i,j)\end{split}$$